# Linux perf tool showing weird cache miss results

Tags: c++, caching, linux-kernel, profiling, perf

I'm using linux perf tools to profile [one of CRONO benchmarks](https://github.com/masabahmad/CRONO/tree/master/apps/apsp), I'm specifically interested in L1 DCache Misses, so I run the program like this:

```
perf record -e L1-dcache-read-misses -o perf/apsp.cycles apps/apsp/apsp 4 16384 16
```

It runs fine but generates those warnings:

```
WARNING: Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are restricted,
check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict.

Samples in kernel functions may not be resolved if a suitable vmlinux
file is not found in the buildid cache or in the vmlinux path.

Samples in kernel modules won't be resolved at all.

If some relocation was applied (e.g. kexec) symbols may be misresolved
even with a suitable vmlinux or kallsyms file.

Cannot read kernel map
Couldn't record kernel reference relocation symbol
Symbol resolution may be skewed if relocation was used (e.g. kexec).
Check /proc/kallsyms permission or run as root.

Threads Returned!
Threads Joined!
Time: 2.932636 seconds
[ perf record: Woken up 5 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.709 MB perf/apsp.cycles (44765 samples) ]
```

I then annotate the output file like this:

```
perf annotate --stdio -i perf/apsp.cycles --dsos=apsp
```

But in one of the code sections, I see some weird results:

```
Percent |      Source code & Disassembly of apsp for L1-dcache-read-misses
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         :               {
         :                  if((D[W_index[v][i]] > (D[v] + W[v][i])))
   19.36 :        401140:       movslq (%r10,%rcx,4),%rsi
   14.50 :        401144:       lea    (%rax,%rsi,4),%rdi
    1.22 :        401148:       mov    (%r9,%rcx,4),%esi
    5.82 :        40114c:       add    (%rax,%r8,4),%esi
   20.02 :        401150:       cmp    %esi,(%rdi)
    0.00 :        401152:       jle    401156 <do_work(void*)+0x226>
         :                     D[W_index[v][i]] = D[v] + W[v][i];
    9.72 :        401154:       mov    %esi,(%rdi)
   19.93 :        401156:       add    $0x1,%rcx
         :
```

Now in those results, How come that some arithmetic instructions have L1 read misses? Also, how come that instructions of the second statement cause so many cache misses even though they should've brought into cache by the previous if statement?
Am I doing something wrong here? I tried the same on a different machine with root access, it gave me similar results, so I think the warnings I mentioned above are not causing this. But what exactly is going on?

Comment: Can you provide absolute numbers? This would help a lot I think. I would expect slightly more than one cache miss per iteration (D[W_index...]. Perf may show a bit fuzzy results probably, but this relative timings are not helpful in this case.

Comment: @overseas I have no idea how to get absolute numbers from perf. I googled a bit and I can't seem to find any. If I use perf list all the listed events will output percentages like the one shown in my question.

Comment: Check this code here: http://pastebin.com/nr2mHmbS You probably also want to check `man perf_open_event`.

Comment: To get absolute numbers (how many samples was in the function) from perf, we can use `-n` option but it is implemented only for `perf report` command, [not for `perf annotate`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-annotate.c?v=4.10#L403) which is like a bug. Rerun `perf record` with fixed event period like `-c 100000` to get stable sample count, use `perf report` to get sample count for function and then use `perf annotate` to get distribution of events in the function (100% is the total sample count of the current function).

Answer (score 0):

So we have this code:

```
for(v=0;v<N;v++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < DEG; i++)
    {
        if((/* (V2) 1000000000 * */ D[W_index[v][i]] > (D[v] + W[v][i])))
            D[W_index[v][i]] = D[v] + W[v][i];

        Q[v]=0; //Current vertex checked
    }
}
```

Note that I added (V2) as a comment in the code. We below come back to this code.

**First approximation**

Remember that `W_index` is initialized as `W_index[i][j] = i + j` ***(A)***.

Let's focus on one inner iteration, and first let's assume that `DEG` is large. Further we assume that the cache is large enough to hold all data for at least two iterations.

```
D[W_index[v][i]]
```

The lookup `W_index[v]` is loaded into a register. For `W_index[v][i]` we assume one cache miss (64 byte cache line, 4 byte per int, we call the programm with DIM=16). The lookup in `D` starts always at `v`, so most of the required part of the array is already in cache. With the assumption that `DEG` is large this lookup is for free.

```
D[v] + W[v][i]
```

The lookup `D[v]` is for free as it depends on `v`. The second lookup is the same as above, one cache miss for the second dimension.

The whole inner statement has no influence.

```
Q[v]=0;
```

As this is `v`, this can be ignored.

When we sum up, we get two cache misses.

**Second approximation**

Now, we come back to the assumption that `DEG` is large. In fact this is wrong because `DEG = 16`. So there are fractions of cache misses we also need to consider.

```
D[W_index[v][i]]
```

The lookup `W_index[v]` costs 1/8 of a cache miss (it has a size of 8 bytes, a cache line is 64 byte, so we get a cache miss each eigth iteration).

The same is true for `D[W_index[v][i]]`, except that `D` holds integers. In average all but one integer are in cache, so this costs 1/16 of a cache miss.

```
D[v] + W[v][i]
```

`D[v]` is already in cache (this is `W_index[v][0]`). But we get another 1/8 of a cache miss for `W[v]` for the same reasoning as above.

```
Q[v]=0;
```

This is another 1/16 of a cache miss.

And surprize, if we now use the code (V2) where the `if`-clause never evaluates to `true`, I get 2.395 cache misses per iteration (note that you really need to configure your CPU well, i.e., no hyperthreading, no turboboost, performance governor if possible). The calculation above would lead to 2.375. So we are pretty good.

**Third approximation**

Now there is this unfortunate `if` clause. How often does this comparison evaluate to `true`. We can't say, in the beginning it will be quite often, and in the end it will never evaluate to `true`.

So let's focus on the really first execution of the complete loop. In this case, `D[v]` is infinity and `W[v][i]` is a number between 1 and 101. So the loop evaluates to `true` in each iteration.

And then it gets hard - we get 2.9 cache misses in this iteration. Where are they coming from - all data should already be in cache.

*But*: This is the "mystery of compilers". You never know what they produce in the end. I compiled with GCC and Clang and get the same measures. I activate `-funroll-loops`, and suddenly I get 2.5 cache misses. Of course this may be different on your system. When I inspected the assembly, I observed that it is really exactly the same, just the loop has been unrolled four times.

So what does this tell us? You never know what your compiler does except you check it. And even then, you can't be sure.

I guess hardware prefetching or execution order could have an influence here. But this is a mystery.

**Regarding perf and your problems with it**

I think the measurements you did have two problems:

- They are relative, the exact line is not that accurate.
- You are multithreaded, this may be harder to track.

My experience is that when you want to get good measures for a specific part of your code, you really need to check it manually. Sometimes - not always - it can explain things pretty good.

Comment: When you want to start with something, you can take this. But this is only debugging code, so I won't add it to the answer (when you look at it, you see why) http://pastebin.com/F7nDzrQi